# How to catch coordinates of mouse cursor (IDE Delphi) to invoke Context Menu

Tags: delphi, ide, components, contextmenu, toolsapi

How to catch coordinates of mouse cursor (IDE Delphi) when I invoke Context Menu to create a new control?

I'd like to create a new control via Context Menu at same coordinates where Context Menu was invoked.

I'm creating my own component editor to do this, then I need the coordinates of mouse to create the control there.

Comment: Unfortunately [a context menu can also be invoked via keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key).

Comment: @TomBrunberg The second sentence makes it clear when you exchange "a new component" with "a new control". I can imagine something like "add e new edit control to this form at the position  where I just right-clicked".

Comment: It seems both current answers do not consider the `ide` and `toolsapi` tags.

Comment: I'm creating a ComponentEditor form to create/configure a new control. I need to know the mouse coordinates, like the IDE's Default Context Menu does, to create the control at that position.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question well, but there are some ways to capture position of your mouse:

**Method 1 - Capture the mouse position on your screen**:
Here you can use `TMouse` class like this:

```
var
  m: TMouse;
begin
  lbl_cordinate_screen.Caption := format('Mouse cordinate on screen: x:%d, y:%d', 
                                          [m.CursorPos.X, m.CursorPos.y]);
end;
```

**Method 2 - Capture the mouse position on a control:**
Here you can use `GetCursorPos`, I declared a function called `cursorCordinate`, it will receive a control name (I used my form named `frm_main` as given control but it can be any other control like a button, label or anything else) and it will return a `TPoint` value containing position of mouse on given control:

```
//function to capture mouse position on a control
function cursorCordinate(myCtrl: TWinControl): TPoint;
var
  mouse_p: TPoint;
begin
  GetCursorPos(mouse_p);
  ScreenToClient(myCtrl.Handle, mouse_p );
  result := mouse_p;
end;
```

*usage example:*

```
begin
  lbl_cordinate_form_1.Caption := format('Mouse cordinate on form: x:%d, y:%d',  
                                          [cursorCordinate(frm_main).X, cursorCordinate(frm_main).y]);
end;
```

**Method 3 - Another way to capture the mouse position on a control:**
Here you can use control's `OnMouseMove` event and its `X` and `Y` parameters, just place your code block in this event. I used it to show mouse position on my form (`frm_main`) in a label (`lbl_cordinate_form_2`), but you can use any other control's `OnMouseMove` event:

```
procedure Tfrm_main.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
lbl_cordinate_form_2.Caption := format('Mouse cordinate on form: x:%d, y:%d', [x, y]);
end;
```

You can see the result in image; first line is result of **Method 1**, second line for **Method 2** and third line belongs to **Method 3**:

[image: Capturing Mouse Position]

Answer (score 0):

By add this cod to **FormContextPopup** can obtain mouse position

```
   uses FMX.Forms;
   ...
   ...
 procedure TForm88.FormContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
      var Handled: Boolean);
    begin
      Label1.Caption:=FMX.Forms.Screen.MousePos.X.ToString+' 
           '+FMX.Forms.Screen.MousePos.Y.ToString;
    
    end;
```